# I want event of song delete in our app when user delete song from music app while our app is running

Tags: ios, xcode7, avfoundation, mpmediaitem

**How to get callback in our app when user delete song from music app.**

**Is there any solution?**

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any system notification about it. I would suggest you to  monitor for music folder and find out when something is removed.

Here is apple example for file manager monitor
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DocInteraction/Listings/Classes_DirectoryWatcher_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010052-Classes_DirectoryWatcher_h-DontLinkElementID_5